# Print out the zombie's name and graveyard. Rails for Zombies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-for-zombies

How to print out the zombie's name and graveyard

Can you concatenate this without adding a string?

```
z = zombie.find(3)

puts z.name
puts z.graveyard
```

Is this wrong?  It is only outputing the last one, graveyard.

Comment: `puts "#{z.name} #{z.graveyard}"`

Comment: Thank you that works.  Can you explain how the # works in this example?

Comment: @NARKOZ: This should be in answer, not in a comment ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use

```
puts "#{z.name} #{z.graveyard}"
```

You might be wondering how this would get evaluated! You should look at [Interpolation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Interpolation). The result of the expressions `z.name` and `z.graveyard` gets concatenated/inserted into the string. Any expression that goes into `#{ }` gets evaluated and inserted into the string

Answer (score 3):

`puts "#{z.name} #{z.graveyard}"`

It's called string [interpolation](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Interpolation).