# How can I use variables within model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model

I'm trying to insert the URL of the page into uploaded image.
I already have the code like this below but it doesn't work.

Is there something wrong in my model?  How can I fix this?

**My associations**

- User has_one :profile
- Profile belongs_to :user

**models/user.rb**

```
before_save :text_to_insert? 

def text_to_insert
    nickname = self.profile.nickname 
end

has_attached_file :user_avatar,
    :styles => {
    :thumb=> "100x100>",
    :small  => "400x400>" }, 
     :convert_options => {
     :small => '-fill white  -undercolor "#00000080"  -gravity South -annotate +0+5 " example.com/'+ nickname +' "' }
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure but I think you want to look at interpolation. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11058271/print-out-the-zombies-name-and-graveyard-rails-for-zombies/11058367#11058367

Comment: In addition, if you don't know how to get the URL of the current page, have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165665/how-do-i-get-the-current-url-in-ruby-on-rails

Comment: I know how to access to columns from controller or view but model:(

Answer (score 1):

before saving , you are using `text_to_insert?` method which doesn't exist thatwhy it is returning false,so it fails to save . 
It looks like typos ,try removing `?` after `:text_to_insert` ie

```
before_save :text_to_insert
```

Please be sure that is valid `self.profile.nickname`

Comment: It still says this error **syntax error, unexpected tUPLUS, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('** Is the way of coding wrong with :convert_options?

Comment: if I code self.profile.nickname, here self means current accessing record of **User** right?

Comment: try checking `has_attached_file` and check whether it accepts `options={}` or not  . generally this is `p = { :n => 'd' }` valid code and `:n => {:s => 'bar'}` is invalid